# HTML data-source PHP script returning uncaught error

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have an issue where when I define:

`data-source="test.json"`

or

`data-source="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"`

in my HTML I am able so successfully get ajax to populate my `<select>` field but when I try to use `data-source="my.php"` I get an uncaught typeerror.

I tried escaping the URL in `file_get_contents()` but i'm not so sure that's the issue.

Here is my HTML select box:

```
<select style="width: 300px;" name="imei" id="selectID" data-source="my.php" data-valueKey="id" data-displayKey="name" data-rel="chosen" class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" class="controls" style="display: ;"></select>
```

Here is how `my.php` file looks:

```
<?php

$JSONURL = file_get_contents("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
$readytoprocess = json_decode($JSONURL);
//

?>
```

Here is how my jquery looks:

```
$('select[data-source]').each(function() {
  var $select = $(this);

  $select.append('<option></option>');

  $.ajax({
    url: $select.attr('data-source'),
  }).then(function(options) {
    options.map(function(option) {
      var $option = $('<option>');

      $option
        .val(option[$select.attr('data-valueKey')])
        .text(option[$select.attr('data-displayKey')]);

      $select.append($option);
      $option.trigger("chosen:updated"); //update table
    });
  });
});
```

I would like `data-source=` to allow me to use `my.php` with `json_decode()`, It makes sense to but I can't figure out why it gives me an error when running.

I am working from [this](https://travishorn.com/populate-select-via-ajax-f2f088a47750) example

Comment: Why is the URL string enclosed in three sets of double quotes?  If the `file_get_contents()` succeeds and you can `json_decode()` its result, you would then need to `echo $readytoprocess;` to provide output from PHP that your JS and HTML can use.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski sorry left it in when trying to escape

Comment: May I ask what you do with `$readytoprocess` ?

Comment: In that case, you might only need to supply some output with `echo`. But, what specific output do you expect to have from my.php? By calling json_decode(), you are producing a data structure for PHP's use, not for JS/HTML's use.  On the PHP side, if you have not verified whether the file_get_contents() succeeded, check that first, and also always when developing code `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your script.

Comment: Just `echo $JSONURL;`

Comment: @AbraCadaver I did but I get the same error: Uncaught TypeError: options.map is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `my.php` file will return a valid JSON resource (which jQuery will autodetect) then your PHP needs to return the JSON data.

```
<?php

  $json = file_get_contents("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  $json = json_decode($json);
  // ----
  // Process your $json with PHP here...
  // ----
  $json = json_encode($json);
  echo $json;

?>
```

And as for populating your `select` with the JSON resource:

```js
$('select[data-source]').each(function() {
  var $select = $(this);
  var valueKey = $select.attr('data-valueKey');
  var displayKey = $select.attr('data-displayKey');

  $.getJSON($select.attr('data-source')).done(function(options) {
    options.map(function(option) {
      var $option = $(document.createElement('option'))
        .val(option[valueKey])
        .text(option[displayKey])
        .appendTo($select)
        .trigger('chosen:updated')
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select data-source="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users" data-valueKey="id" data-displayKey="name"></select>
```

---

> Make sure to include the jQuery library followed by your code. This is best placed at the end of your document as close to `</body>` as possible. Subsequently, if your code throws errors it's easier to track the issue.

Comment: Thanks it works. looks like the jquery had to be changed quite a bit to get it to work with a php script.